# How do I make a repeated if statement into a php array using foreach?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

In PHP, I'm trying to add a different colored block for each different type of music genre. Each color represents a specific genre. I have 12 genres, but I've only included 3 of those for simplification purposes.

First I get the genre value with

```
$genre = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'genre', true);
```

Then I'm using an if statement like so (though it doesn't work past the 2nd genre)

```
if($genre == "EDM")
echo '<div style="display:block;width:100%;height:10px;background-color:#9B86FF;"></div>';

else if($genre == "Hip-Hop")
echo '<div style="display:block;width:100%;height:10px;background-color:#56FFCE;"></div>';

else if($genre == "Rock")
echo '<div style="display:block;width:100%;height:10px;background-color:#56CBFD;"></div>';
```

It works for EDM and Hip-Hop, but stops working after Hip-Hop.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: make your hip hop to string like "Hip-Hop"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?

```
$genre_colors = array("EDM" => "9B86FF", "Hip-Hop" => "56FFCE", "Rock" => "56CBFD");
$color = $genre_colors[get_post_meta($post->ID, 'genre', true)];
if ($color !== null)
  echo '<div style="display:block;width:100%;height:10px;background-color:#' . $color . ';"></div>';
```

Comment: Removed the hash from the EDM color hex value and this worked beautifully! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Good Answer :) You can also write your last statement as:  echo "<div style='display:block;width:100%;height:10px;background-color:#E6E6FA';></div>";